# What's wrong with my auto layout constraints in my xib file?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, xib

I have a `xib` file that I am planning to load into a `UIScrollView` in my `UIViewController`.

Here you can download the xib file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=13327266143771794775.

It looks like this:

[image]

The views with the number 1 are the views with a fixed height.

The views with the number 2 are the views with a variable height. Those views must be able to expand as much as they want, creating eventually a scroll.

I don't understand why it says some constraints are missing. I tried to change priorities but without success.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Shi##y link, clicked on download opened 2-4 ad links...use some better services.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice with my add blocker. Any good service you know for me to use?

Comment: You better use `UIStackView` for this kind of design

Comment: Haven't check what `UIStackView` is yet but the problem is that's it's available from iOS 9 while my project works for iOS 8 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the below views are the subclass of UIview you need to give a constant height for either any one of 2's as shown in below image. As uiview is a container [image]

and if you want the both heights equal select both the views and make the equal width [image]

use Remove at build time if the content will be added programmatically [image]

Comment: Yes I saw that but if I give a fixed height to one of them (let's say the 1rst one), how do I manage it when the 1rst view is bigger or way smaller than the fixed height I gave it?

Comment: so you want both the heights equal ?

Comment: No. I would like the height of each view equal to its content how ever big it is.

Comment: but i didnt see any content in it

Comment: I will add it programmatically.

Comment: you have two options 1) add a content view inside container... 2) give constant height

Comment: ok. Thank you, I'll have the constant height and remove it at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You should add height constraints to comments View and write comments View. In size inspector Tick the "Remove at build time" for these two height constraints.